# How select unique color for data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I need to draw `Tsne` for different vector representations for different 84 type.

```
library(Rtsne); library(ggplot2)

mydata <- read.table("tsneVectors.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t")

matrixdata <- data.matrix(mydata)

tsne <- Rtsne(as.matrix(matrixdata[ ,2:201]), check_duplicates = FALSE, pca = FALSE, 
              perplexity=30, theta=0.5, dims=2)

tsne_plot <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[ ,1], y = tsne$Y[ ,2], col = matrixdata[ ,202])

ggplot(tsne_plot) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(col))) + 
    labs(x="", y="", col="col")+theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + theme_bw()
```

The problem is that although the colors seem to be continuous, sometimes its really hard to see the difference between them.

[image]

So, is there any way to set distinct colors to see the different groups more clearly?

Comment: The problem is that you want points of 84 colors

Comment: I mean even if there're continues colors but consider just the first color (not the whole range that's not clear to see the different between them) @paoloeusebi

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's even possible to find 84 colors that are easily distinguishable to the human eye.

Split them up into multiple plots with 10-15 groups per plot.

The `gridExtra` package with the `grid.arrange()` function would be useful for this.

Comment: I understand you, but I need them all in order to compare them. but I mean even if there're continues colors but consider just the first color (not the whole range that's not clear to see the different between them)

Comment: How about using multiple plots, and highlighting a select few with colors in each one, leaving the rest black?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try breaking the continuous variable according to suitable cut points. It is straightforward using `cut`, which divides the range of color aesthetic into intervals labelled according to which interval they fall.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 col_intervals <- 3
 ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, colour = cut(hp, col_intervals)) ) + 
 geom_point()
```

[image]

Another option

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt) ) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = hp)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10))
```

[image]

Comment: what's variable hp?

Comment: hp=gross horsepower / mpg=miles per gallon / wt=weight